# Does なんかいいな and 焼いてるboth refer to jealousy?

Tags: meaning, words

I am looking for some clarification as to the connotations/meanings of both なんかいいな and 焼いてるin the following snippet -

> なんかいいな、と思ってよ。 お前がそんな風に誰かの世話焼いてるところなんて、見たことなかったからな…

I have heard that なんていいな can mean jealousy or envy (but not in a serious way) the above passage says なんかいいな however, か instead of て, Is なんかいいな the same as なんていいな ?

焼いてる Refers to burning, but I've heard that this can also mean jealousy/envy in some instances, looking at the above passage I think this might be right, can someone confirm? With the ところ following it, it makes me think that it could mean 'on the verge of jealousy' is that right?

Comment: 「やく」 can mean “to be jealous” in some context (not in this one), and in such cases it is written as 「妬く」.

Answer (score 5):

> 「なんかいいな、と思{おも}ってよ。 お前{まえ}がそんな風{ふう}に誰{だれ}かの世話焼{せわや}いてるところなんて、見{み}たことなかったからな…」

You seem a little confused here.  **There is no implied or explicit mention of "jealousy" in this passage**.  Sorry if this comes as a surprise, but someone has to say it.

「なんかいいな」 could express jealousy in other contexts but not here.  It only means "**It's kinda nice.**" here.

> " Is なんかいいな the same as なんていいな ?"

No, not at all.  「なんか」, as I used in my translation above, means "kinda" or "sorta".  「なんていいな」 cannot replace it in the context in question.

Same goes for 「焼いている」.  You must be imagining another context/situation.

Here, it is used in the idiomatic expression 「世話を焼く」, which means "**to take great care of**" with the nuance "perhaps even too much".

> "With the ところ following it, it makes me think that it could mean 'on the verge of jealousy' is that right?"

No, it is not.  「ところ」 refers to the actual "scene" where the person was taking care of another.